# Error with 'orderby' column not found

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this very simple method in my repository class which fetches a list as query builder object:

```
public function fetchListAsQueryBuilder(User $user, $receiverType, $limit, $offset)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $queryBuilder
        ->select(['no'])
        ->from('SLCoreBundle:Notification', 'no')
        ->where('no.receiver = :user')
        ->andWhere('no.receiverType = :receiverType')
        ->orderBy('no.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->setParameters([
            'user' => $user,
            'receiverType' => $receiverType,
        ])
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ;

    return $query;
}
```

this method works perfectly in my prod server, but gives an error in my local machine, php versions are same(5.5.9), here is an error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT id_6 FROM
>   (SELECT s0_.receiver_type AS receiver_type_0, s0_.importance AS
>   importance_1, s0_.seen AS seen_2, s0_.deleted AS deleted_3,
>   s0_.created_at AS created_at_4, s0_.updated_at AS updated_at_5, s0_.id
>   AS id_6, s0_.reason AS reason_7 FROM sl_notification s0_ WHERE
>   s0_.receiver_id = ? AND s0_.receiver_type = ?) dctrn_result ORDER BY
>   s0_.created_at DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0' with params [2, 1]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's0_.created_at' in 'order clause'

My entity has been configured like this:

Mapped superclass AbstractMessage:

```
abstract class AbstractMessage
{
    use CreatedUpdatedAtTrait;

    // here go properties, setters and getter
```

Notification class:

```
class Notification extends AbstractMessage
{
    // here go properties, setters and getters
```

And CreateUpdatedAtTrait:

```
trait CreatedUpdatedAtTrait
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    // Here go setters and getters
}
```

Schema (AbstractMessage) :

```
<mapped-superclass name="SL\CoreBundle\Entity\AbstractMessage">

    ... 

    <field name="createdAt" column="created_at" type="datetime">
        <gedmo:timestampable on="create" />
    </field>

    <field name="updatedAt" column="updated_at" type="datetime">
        <gedmo:timestampable on="update" />
    </field>

</mapped-superclass>
```

here is the db table:
[image]

I'dont understand what causes this error, my others entities work well with this trait, and also my other queries with `orderBy` method and mappedsuperclass classes work without any error. And also very interesting part is if I remove `orderBy` my method is working and I am able to get the `createdAt` value (`$object->getCreatedAt()`). Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, that I've recently updated vendors to the latest versions(sf-2.6.6, DoctrineORM-2.5.0).

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard yes, I already updated it. No luck.

Comment: Ok, and can you confirm that the attribute is named ```createdAt``` in your entity configuration (yaml, annotations, ...)?

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard I updated my question, added the schema.

Comment: I don't know of any other pitfalls that could cause this, I'm sorry.

Comment: Did you update your schema? Run `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` and/or `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`. Do you get any helpful output?

Comment: @ggioffreda Yes, I've already ran those commands, `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` shows that everything is OK, `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` shows `Nothing to update...`..

Comment: Now that I read the query more carefully it's clearly wrong, the subquery has a field `s0_.created_at` while the outer query should order by `created_at_4` for the same reason it selects `id_6` correctly instead of the incorrect `s0_.id`. Did you run a composer update on your local machine or are you using any edge/alpha/dev/custom version of Doctrine? That would also explain while it does work on the server and not on your machine. You could try and grab the `composer.lock` file from the server and run `composer install` on your machine to double check.

Comment: @ggioffreda I've edited my question.. Yes, ive recently updated the vendors.

Comment: Yes, it can be an issue. Try and revert to the previous version and see if the problem goes away, you might have found a bug. Also an `app/console cache:clear` cannot do any harm... just in case :)

Comment: @ggioffreda wow, good shot. I realized that I didn't run the `composer install` in my prod server, so my local doctrine version was - 2.5.0, prod 2.4.0; Looks like something has been changed in newer version, but I didn't find any information about this behavior.. May be I should open an issue in doctrine repo?

Comment: @ggioffreda My bad, I can see some changes to the OrderBy in [changelog](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2015/04/02/orm-2-5-0.html), but I don't understand, why this is happening, how to order records then? very interesting..

Comment: I just got a message from SO to avoid extended discussions in comments so I apologise if I don't reply to this one. You should definitely fire a bug to the Doctrine guys if you can find a way to reproduce the issue. If they can see it, they can fix it and that'll help the community. The syntax in that query you posted is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's cause by doctrine 2.5 +

So i switched back to 2.4.7 and its working again !

In my composer.json

```
"require": {
    ...
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.7",
    ...
}
```

And update

```
php composer.phar update
```

Comment: I have faced the same issue so  registered a bug http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3872

Comment: Version 2.5.1 also seems does not have the issue all other 2.5.2 has it.